# Are there names for checkers openings?

Tags: openings, checkers

I have never heard of one; but I don't know where to look to make sure.  This is something I've been wondering for a long time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, here's a [link](http://www.bobnewell.net/checkers/principles.html) that talks about an example, The Switcher.

And here's a [great link](http://www.usacheckers.com/openingnames.php) that lists them all.

Comment: Wow!  Where did you find all that?

Comment: My friend called google.